# Adding a custom language file to CKEditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

Is there a way to add a new language to CKEditor? I want to integrate an aspx page that reads values from a dictionary database to the editor.

Things I've done already:

- added `language: 'dictionary'` to config
- added a file called `dictionary.js` (starting with `CKEDITOR.lang['dictionary']`) to the lang directory
- added `dictionary: 'Dictionary'` to the language array in _languages.js

But sofar it's not showing the translations I've defined

Is there something I forgot to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out

You have to override lang.languages and add the new language

```
CKEDITOR.lang.languages =
{
    'dictionary':1,
    'afl':1,
     etc.
```